# Is it possible to know the most searched keywords?

Tags: feature-request, search, data-analysis

It would be interesting to know what people are the most searching that is strongly different from what is available on the site.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the most-viewed items, and that's probably more useful.

Anyway, StackOverflow's searches don't tell the whole story.  To really see a complete picture you'd also want to know about Google searches that ultimately led to StackOverflow pages.

Comment: http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com click "Search Analytics"

Comment: @Kop: lol at 5 of the top 10 searches having the keyword *jquery*

Comment: The way I understand the OP, he'd rather want to know about Google searches that *did not* lead to StackOverflow pages. jQuery is the perfect example of what is **not** "strongly different from what is available on the site". @Kop.